# react hook how to handle mutiple checkbox

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const shoopingList = [{name:'some thing', id:1},{name:'some string', id:4}]

const CurrentLists = ({ shoppingList }) => {
    const arr = [...shoppingList]
    arr.map((item, index) => {
        item.isChecked = false
    })
    const [checkedItems, setCheckeditems] = useState(arr)
    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        const index = e.target.name
        const val = e.target.checked
        checkedItems[index].isChecked = e.target.checked
        setCheckeditems([...checkedItems])
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {checkedItems.map((item, index) => {
                console.log('item check', item.isChecked)
                return (
                    <CheckBox
                        key={index}
                        name={index}
                        checked={item.isChecked}
                        text={item.name}
                        onChange={handleOnChange}
                    />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```js
const CheckBox = ({ checked, onChange, text, className = '', name }) => {
    let css = classnames({
        activebox: checked,
    })
    return (
        <div className={'CheckBoxComponent ' + className}>
            <div className={'checkbox ' + css}>
                <input
                    name={name}
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={onChange}
                />
                {checked && <i className="far fa-check signcheck" />}
            </div>
            <label>{text}</label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I got some checkboxes. when I click the checkbox, my component doesn't re-render. What's wrong here? I might be using the hook setState wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On every re-render you are basically setting `isChecked` property to `false`. Try updating your component like this:

```
const CurrentLists = ({ shoppingList }) => {
  const [checkedItems, setCheckeditems] = useState(shoppingList)

  const handleOnChange = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      const index = e.target.name
      let items = [...checkedItems];
      items[index].isChecked = e.target.checked;
      setCheckeditems(items);
    }, [checkedItems]
  );
  return (
      <div>
          {checkedItems.map((item, index) => {
              console.log('item check', item.isChecked)
              return (
                  <CheckBox
                      key={index}
                      name={index}
                      checked={item.isChecked}
                      text={item.name}
                      onChange={handleOnChange}
                  />
              )
          })}
      </div>
  )
}
```

You may also notice usage of `useCallback`. It ensures that your callback is memoized and not created on every re-render - [more about it](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Comment: I think you can improve the code by specifying the second argument of `useCallback`, it should be `useCallback(e => {...}, [])`

Comment: Using @OlivierBoissé's suggestion means that useCallback won't update every time render does. If the callback depends on additional state, it needs to be added to the second argument array.

Comment: yes it should be `useCallback(e => {...}, [checkedItems])` instead of `useCallback(e => {...}, [])` otherwise the `checkedItems` in the callback function will keep the reference of the initial value => `shoppingList`

Answer (score 1):

In `handleOnChange` you are mutating the state directly, and because the state reference is not changed React does not re-render. To fix this change the line `setCheckeditems(checkedItems)` to `setCheckeditems([...checkedItems])`.

Also in your render, you are rendering `shoppingList`, but what you need to render is `checkedItems`

Comment: I made the change as your suggestion, it still not working. The component now rerender when i click, however, the isChecked properties are false always. it doesn't change